# Get latest entry in each week over several years period

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table to store history for entities:

```
    Date                   Id        State
    -------------------------------------
    2017-10-10              1        0
    2017-10-12              1        4
    2018-5-30               1        8
    2019-4-1                2        0
    2018-3-6                2        4
    2018-3-7                2        0
```

I want to get last entry for each Id in one week period e.g.

```
    Date                   Id        State
    -------------------------------------
    2017-10-12              1        4
    2018-5-30               1        8
    2019-4-1                2        0
    2018-3-7                2        0
```

I'd try to use `Partition by`:

```
select
        ID
       ,Date
        ,State
        ,DatePart(week,Date) as weekNumber
        from TableA
where   Date = (
            select max(Date) over (Partition by Id Order by DatePart(week, Date) Desc)
        )
order by ID
```

but it still gives me more than one result per week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (SELECT a.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.id, DATEPART(WK, a.Date) ORDER BY a.Date DESC) AS Seq
      FROM tablea a
     ) a
WHERE seq = 1
ORDER BY id, Date;
```